# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.jaxb.suninternal.NamespacePrefixMapper -Docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I updated docx4j from **6.1.2 to 8.0.0** version (https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-8-0-0-released-t2808.html). I'm using **docx4j-JAXB-Internal**. When I try to execute, I'm getting the following exception:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Can't create internal NamespacePrefixMapper
- with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.jaxb.suninternal.NamespacePrefixMapper]
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:67)
at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.marshaltoString(XmlUtils.java:850)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.docx4j.jaxb.suninternal.NamespacePrefixMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:63)
... 6 more
```

**Code:**

```
public class VersionTest {

  final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VersionTest.class);

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Docx4JException {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File("/home/ubuntu/Documents/Projects/Java_Workspace/Version_Test/input/test.docx"));
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    EndnotesPart endnotePart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getEndNotesPart();
    FootnotesPart footnotesPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFootnotesPart();
    CommentsPart comments = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getCommentsPart();

    logger.info("documentPart Info  "+XmlUtils.marshaltoString(documentPart.getJaxbElement(), true, true) );    
}}
```

Help me out to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform are you running your application on?

Comment: Suggest that instead of upgrading to 8.0.0, you upgrade to 8.2.9 or 8.3.0

Comment: On the face of it, it appears that docx4j-JAXB-Internal is not on your class path, so double check that.

Comment: @JasonPlutext. Yes, problem in maven update.

Comment: I found a strange problem while updating the version. When I use docx4j-6.1.2, I've not mentioned log4j-1.2.17 in my pom. But it gets automatically added to my project. When I use docx4j-8.3.0, log4j is not added to my project and there is a failure in maven update. That's why  docx4j-JAXB-Internal is not added to my project.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_242"